# Manhwa about a teenager who was being raised as mercenary

Tags: story-identification, manga

It’s a story about a teenager who was being raised by a smoker as mercenary, typical action story set in a world where monster appears.

I remember him having this staff like weapon that ended up being an incomplete weapon given to his father that was passed down to him.

He also met a magic archer who’s older sister was very popular and bullied her along with the “strongest” tank in the school (had white hair and I remember them playing games together in an internet café before a fight happened) who ended up just being really socially awkward.

Here is a screenshot I have from the manhwa explaining how mana works:

[image: three people on a starry background with a flame of varying height next to each of them]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Google tells me that the image is associated with a manhwa called "Warrior High School," but the first chapter doesn't seem to match up with what you're describing.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you DavidW. The name is ***[Warrior High School](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/x0yjpbp/yongsa-high-dungeon-raiders)***.

> A cosmic anomaly has opened interdimensional breaches on Earth, creating exotic hybrid environments called "dungeons" inhabited by deadly otherworldly creatures. Yoo Jaryong, left to fend for himself as his father's health deteriorates, secretly cultivates the superhuman potential arising from the anomaly and becomes a dungeon smuggler to pay his bills. When elite dungeon raiders discover his skills, he is given the chance to train at the alma mater of the world's heroes: Yongsa High School.

Comment: Hi. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. However, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.